# invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand C pointers. I tried this simple code:

```
double der(double a)
{
    //printf("Value of a is %d\n", a);
    return (cos(a+eps)-cos(a-eps))/(2*eps);
}

void EX5(){

    double x;
    double (*fun_pointer)(double) = &der;
    printf ("saisir un point ");
    scanf ("%lf",&x);
    printf ("cos reel = %lf \n", cos(x));
    printf ("cos approximatif = %lf", der(x));
    double *r;
    r=*(fun_pointer)(x);
    printf ("cos approximatif = %lf", r);

}
```

But I get

```
invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have 'double')
```

Where Am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
    double r;
    r = fun_pointer(x);
```

The function returns a `double`, not `double*`, so you don't need to dereference it.

It's not necessary to dereference a function pointer when calling it, this is done automatically.